# selecting, deselecting of textViews on first longpress followed by single clicks

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

i'am giving a functionality of selecting and deselecting of collection of textViews which is not in ListView. On very first long press of any textview it will select the textView after that any single click will select or deselect the textviews like in whatsapp. All textViews are created runtime. here i'am pasting my code for longClick and simple click-

```
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //boolean selected = !v.isSelected();
            selectedViews++;
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
            boolean selected = !tv.isSelected();
            tv.setSelected(selected);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(selected ? Color.parseColor("#808080"): Color.WHITE);
            if(selected) {
                mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                mActionMode.setTitle(selectedViews + " selected");
                keys.add(tv.getId());
                itemList.put(tv.getId(), tv.getText().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(selectedViews > 0){
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(v.getId());
                boolean selected = !tv.isSelected();
                tv.setSelected(selected);
                tv.setBackgroundColor(selected ? Color.parseColor("#808080"): Color.WHITE);
                if(selected){
                    selectedViews++;
                    mActionMode.setTitle(selectedViews+" selected");
                    keys.add(tv.getId());
                    itemList.put(tv.getId(), tv.getText().toString());
                }else{
                    selectedViews--;
                    if(selectedViews == 0)
                        mActionMode.finish();
                    else
                        mActionMode.setTitle(selectedViews+ " selected");
                    keys.remove(tv.getId());
                    itemList.remove(tv.getId());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

the issue is this code selecting the textViews correctly but while deselecting for some textViews it is working fine but for others it's not working and crashing on random basis, specially the textView which i selected through lonPress is never deselecting by single crash. 
Here i'am pasting my crash logs-

```
07-30 08:47:46.389 2460-2460/com.example.rekhahindwar.applinksaver D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-30 08:47:46.389 2460-2460/com.example.rekhahindwar.applinksaver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.rekhahindwar.applinksaver, PID: 2460
                                                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
```

for above logs i selected 3 textViews successfully deselected one textView on clicking the other textView for deselecting , which was selected through single click, app crashed.

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: it's selecting the textViews coreectly... but while deselecting for some textViews it is deselecting fine but for others on clicking app crashes.

Comment: Make sure to add this to your post so others understand the issue.

Comment: Post your crashlogs

Comment: Start at the first line of the error message and scan down until you find a line of the error that refers to code that you wrote. Find out why that line of code causes the error.

Comment: ok wait a minute

Comment: Since you are using android studio, the console should have a hyperlink to the line throwing the OutOfBounds exception.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i solved my problem... :)